# Figuring out how many items in a complex custom CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to figure out how many items I need to display within a CollectionView. The user is able to select any whole number of gray items (between 1-1000). After every 16 gray items, I need to display two red boxes on the end/beginning of the collection view. For example: if the user wants 33 gray items displayed, then it need to show 5 red items plus the 33 gray items.

[image: collection view boxes layout]

This is the algorithm that I've been using but it's not returning the correct amount of gray items.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
      let userChosenValue = Int(settingsArray[0].userChosenValue)
      var redItemValue = ((userChosenValue * 2) + 1) / 18
         
      return userChosenValue.count + redItemValue
  
    
}
```

Comment: What happens if a value less than 16 is chosen? Why does your example contain 37 instead of 33 grey boxes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If a value is less than 16 then it needs to show one red box as the very first cell like it is in the example and then the chosen value amount of gray boxes. It needs to work with any number so that's why I have a random number of 37 boxes shown and not 33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math isn't that complicated but lets break it down.

The number of whole groups (16) of grey you need is

```
let numberOfGreyGroups = userChosenValue / 16
```

and the remaining number of grey boxes is

```
let restOfGrey = userChosenValue % 16
```

Then the number of red boxes becomes

```
let numberOfRed = numberOfGreyGroups * 2 + (restOfGrey > 0 ? 1 : 0)
```